# How to detect touching on a glass with Object Tracking?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I am working at a Biomedical Center right now and my task is to track both pawns of rats and count the number of times they touch the glass surface.

To elaborate. I have a setup that contains one glass cylinder and 4 cameras that record the rat at 4 perpendicular angles. I need to train a model to track the rat's left and right pawn and count the times that which one touches the cylinder.

I am using DeepLabCut for labeling and resnet50 for training. I got the object tracking part but my question is how I can detect whether the rat is touching the cylinder or not?

Here is a image of the setup I am working on.

[image: Image of the setup]

Comment: If you see the same paw in at least two views, you can find the 3D coordinates by triangulation. Then plug in the equation of the glass (a cone) to check closeness to the surface.

Comment: But isn't it enough to count when the rats stand ?

Comment: It is not enough to count when the rat stands because sometimes it doesn't even touch the glass while standing up. I think the triangulation may work but I need to do some additional work for it.

Comment: You'll never be sure if the glass was effectively touched. And is touching more important (more indicative) than standing ??

Comment: "I need to do some additional work for it": said in my comment.